# Line Graph in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Two-line graph with slicers:  Everything looks fine until date selections are made.

I figure that this failure has something to do with the line graph and date functionality.  Date selections work together in a very weird way.  Selecting only 2019 months and then only 2020 months, both lines disappear.

If the date slicers are going to work together, I should expect inclusive behavior, rather than "NOT 2020 AND NOT 2019"!

[See relationships.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6IET.png)

How do I get the behavior intended on one two-line graph?

Thanks!

Comment: Despite all the words and the screenshots, I don't see what you want to achieve. I don't have time to reverse-engineer the report  (which is not working as you expect) and then imagine how you would like it to work. So, can you explain what you would like to achieve without us having to open your report and play with it? We may not need your whole data set. A simplified example would be fine.

Comment: No one asked you to "reverse engineer" anything. If you are short on time, please move on; plenty of others here are more capable:  @Gigga got it perfectly...the first time and with just one swing.  Thank you both for your warm welcome.

Comment: Your problem was not stated clearly in your question, so the only way to figure out your requirement involved reverse-engineering. Don't be mad at me for trying to help. I was giving you some hints on how to ask a better question, so more people would find it easier to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @teylyn, sometimes less is more.

The problem is how Power Bi works and how your measures are calculated. You have two averagex-measures, both pointing to same date table. In Power BI, two separate filters from a single dimension can't do "union", they are laid down on top of each other. You are telling that first I want to filter by 2019 November and after the filter has been evaluated, you tell that you want to filter 2020 January. Power BI adds new filter to already filtered dataset, but the dataset doesn't contain anything that match both filters, so the end result is empty.

One way to get around this problem is to create separate date-tables for filtering purposes for blue and green. Here is an example of the data model needed:
[image: example data model]
Then you update the date-filters in second tab. Set blue date filter to one date-dimension and green date filter to another. This way they aren't filtering the same table and the graph should work the same as before.

Comment: Perfect.  I was stuck on the filtering issue that you describe.  I like this approach (and will add it to my toolbox), but I have since implemented a solution that does not create extra tables:  I simply add in PowerQuery the few date columns to each data table and then point the date slicers accordingly (rather than to the DateDim table).  Thanks for your help!